# NGINX Denying Access to CSS and JS in Folder with Location Directive

Tags: nginx, location, directive, permission-denied

I had to send a custom add_header to setup no-cache for a particular folder and sub folders. You can see my sample code below. But, when I set it up, I can no longer access JS and CSS files that share the same folder. If a css is in a subfolder of the protected folder, it's fine, but it gets 403 access denied if in the protected folder.

What I want is all files, including php, to send the no-cache header if in the "/protected" folder or any subfolders of the protected folder. That's it.

If I try location ~ /protected/

I can't access css or js files in any subfolders of /protected/ then.

```
location ^~ /protected/ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/ramrod/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
                 # kill cache
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;

        }
```

I actually thought this was the correct directive:

```
location /protected/ {}
```

And figured this would have all files, especially php or html, return the no-cache header. But that wasn't the case. Only the index returned the header and nothing else. But then they all started returning the no-cache header as they should when I changed it to:

```
location ~ /protected/ {}
```

But then css and js files give a 403 error in the same directory (or sub directory).

My hopeful solution is to have a directive that puts the add_header to all files in a directory and it's subdirectory, but still allows me access to all files.

Comment: Please add the entire configuration for the `server` block. Would `expires 0;` work for you rather than manually adding headers?

Comment: I've had to add this because my new CDN defaults to a long browser cache header, while Cloudflare would add the no-cache for me. But I have to use this particular CDN, and need this directory to have the no-cache header. It's basically an admin directory doing a lot of ajax, so subfolders also doing ajax requests, and the CDN was trying to cache the result. I first want to figure out which directive would make sure that all files and subfolders inside /protected/ folder receive the same rules (and headers).

Comment: ok, this at least seems to have solved the issue: `location ^~ /protected/ {
            location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/ramrod/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
}
                 # kill cache
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;

        }`